# Crop and Export video into circle using swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I want to crop a video in "circle" and store it. This is what I've done so far. But the problem is it only crops the video in rectangle. I want to crop it in circle. How can I do this?

```
    func cropVideo() {

    let asset = AVAsset.init(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "1", ofType: "mp4")!))
    let clipVideoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, height: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height)
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(60, 30))
    let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction.init(assetTrack: clipVideoTrack)
    let t1 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, y: 0)
    let t2 = t1.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    let finalTransform = t2
    transformer.setTransform(finalTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]


    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let exportPath = documentsPath.appendingFormat("/CroppedVideo.mp4")
    let exportUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)
    print("export url  = \(exportUrl)")


    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: exportUrl)
    }
    catch _ {
    }

    exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exporter.outputURL = exportUrl
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
            self.exportDidFinish(self.exporter)
        })
    })
}

func exportDidFinish(_ session: AVAssetExportSession) {
    let outputURL = session.outputURL
    print("outputurl  = \(outputURL)")

}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you mean "how do I make the CGAffineTransform a circle instead of a rectangle?"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my question above is correct, the trick is to use masking and a round image instead of using the `CGAffineTransform`. I suspect there is a way to do it with `CGAffineTransform`, but in the meantime...

- make an image with a transparent circle in the middle
- import that into your project and load it
- add your video layer first, and then the mask image
- export

That should get you what you want. There's a somewhat older tutorial on this [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos), look about half way down.

Comment: It is not actually cropping the video only masking it.

Comment: Indeed, but the end result is the same, no? Or do you want the area outside the circle to "disappear" entirely?

Comment: Yes. I want that disappear.

Comment: There is no way to do this in realtime anyway, so anything along these lines will be an "offline" transform like your example. And as the end result of any movie is still going to be rectangular, the end result will be the same. What exactly is the use-case here?